how to relate OSI Profile (Open Systems Interconnection), OSE/RM Profile (Open System Environment Reference Model) and API Profile?
This needs to be understood as we analyze the existing information system.
Is it possible to say that OSI is a subset of OSE and also a superset of API in all cases?
I didn't get clear distinction between concepts, especially between OSE and OSI and, if possible, specific examples would be interesting.
N.B. In general my question relates to the subject of information technology analysis, which is an introduction to systems engineering. These definitions are taken from ISO/IEC TR 10000 - Information technology Framework and taxonomy of International Standardized Profiles

Welcome to SO. You might want to read [ask] and then update your question. A couple of suggestions: 1) "i expect" may be considered demanding and not well received 2) You might want to show the effort you already put into trying to find an answer, e.g. what did you research already, what do you understand, where's the confusion 3) this question doesn't seem to be related to Java so either remove that tag or explain the relationship.

@Thomas thanks for the corrections. As for Java, I'm interested in examples of systems that show the correlation of profiles to each other. Along the way, I looked at the profile definitions, found a discrepancy, and asked the community to help clarify who understands these concepts and how. I didn't find similar questions in SO

Could you link those profile definitions and point out the discrepancies you found? That might help get a more focused answer. I, for example, am not sure what exactly you're referring to. OSI as in "the OSI model", OSE as in "Oracle Servlet Engine" and API as in "application programming interface"? If so, then the 3 are as related as "code", "UI" and "markup language" (or so) :)

Please tell us what exactly you understand 'OSI', 'OSE', 'OSE/RM', and 'API profile' to mean. I doubt that you really mean the generally accepted meaning of [tag:osi], for example. This is the danger of indiscriminate usage of TLAs.

@user207421 Open System Environment Reference Model for OSE RM,  Open Systems Interconnection for OSI and Application Programming Interfaces for API. Accordingly, a profile means a set of standards or ISP( International standardized profiles)

@Thomas it is not known specifically whether OSE is a complete superset of OSI

OK Now please tell us why you think the 100% obsolete OSI could possibly have anything to do with OSE, OSE/RM, etc. Also what the extremely generic 'Application Programming Interfaces for API' has to do with either,, if indeed it even exists other than as a TLA and buzzword.

The OSI (Open Systems Interconnection) model is not considered obsolete, but rather it still serves as a conceptual framework for understanding and discussing network communication protocols.

You might also want to define how you understand the term "profile" in the context of those 3 models. As you stated, OSI relates to network communication protocols while OSE is an architectural model. API is a very broad term but normally relates to some form of code, markup or general DSL that describes the application level interaction interface.

@serge21shNo it doesn't. It was introduced as a conceptual model to describe the OSI suite of protocols. See the OSI documents, which I have, even if you haven't. It was never intended as anything else, although for about 30 years it has been misused as a universal protocol description framework. TCP doesn't conform to it, for example, having its own protocol model, which incidentally predates OSI by decades. IPX/SPX ditto, also SNA and several others. And what this could possibly have to do with OSE, OSE/RM, and 'API' remains an unanswered mystery.

Why you removed the [tag:ose] tag from a question explicitly about OSE is yet another mystery.

both profiles aim to standardize and facilitate interoperability within their respective domains, they operate at different levels of abstraction. It is important to find the limits of applicability and, in mathematical language, to define the sets

But their domains do not overlap, and one is obsolete. There is no intersection, so there is nothing to define. This is just buzzword-itis.

@user207421 OSE tag stands here for Operating System Embedded, but I mean Open System Environment Reference Model. This tag doesn't exist here.

That's further proof that this is just TLA-ism without any rational foundation. The only basis for your question appears to be that both TLAs start with 'OS'. Let me explain mathematically, if that is your bent. The domain of the OSI model is the OSI protocol suite, and the OSI protocol suite presently consists of []. An empty set. So it doesn't intersect with anything.

@Thomas, International Standardized Profiles (ISPs) are profiles that define standardized implementations of specific international standards within the field of information and communication technology (ICT). These profiles ensure interoperability between systems and facilitate the exchange of information and data across different platforms and technologies.
The purpose of ISPs is to provide detailed specifications and guidelines for implementing international standards in practical systems and applications.

@user207421 why did you put again ose tag? its not correct

OSE Profile Model: ISO/IEC TR 10000
OSI and API are included in OSE-Profile as independent parts of interface profiles. The CSI here stands for Communication Service Interface and is part of OSI

Nothing in your link that says anything of the sort.

my link shows the OSE reference model, which exactly shows the correlation of concepts:)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
